# How to search my textfile?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I was hoping someone could offer me a little help here please.  I have a text file which has two columns and each column is separated by a space (“ “), the first column is a string and the second column is a numeric field.

What I’m trying is to read the numeric field in textbox1 and match it to every numeric field in column2 and if the number in textbox1 is not greater than the field then to copy that row (column1 and column 2) into another textfile.

I have the following coding so far.

```
Dim l1Infos = Textbox1.text
        Select New With {.Line = l1, .Tokens = l1.Split(" "c)}
        Dim result = From l1 In l1Infos
                     Join l2 In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test2",)
                     On l1.Tokens(0) Equals l2
                     Select l1.Line
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Test2", result)
```

Comment: What I’m trying is to read the numeric field in textbox1 and match it to every numeric field in column2 and if the numeric field in textbox1 is not greater than the field then to copy that row (column1 and column 2) into another textfile.

Comment: Fabulous.  But what's your question?

Comment: how would I do this? any examples? etc.

Comment: Come on show some effort.  The output file the same as the input.  Select l1 when the file is l2.   On parses l1 but not l2. On l1 you use 0 not 1 and I am not sure that split is even wired up correctly. No where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While jamming as much logic as possible into one statement can be impressive and may win you a code-obfuscation award, sometimes the simpler solution is just plain easier to read, debug, and maintain:

```
    Dim maxValue As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test1")
        If Integer.Parse(line.Split(" "c)(1)) < maxValue Then
            File.AppendAllText("C:\Test2", line)
        End If
    Next
```

I imagine if that doesn't work for you, it will be far easier to figure out why not.  It's even one less line of code to boot!